# Fortran 77 codes works but does not show all values

Tags: fortran, fortran77

My program works, but it does not show all P(I) values.

When its work it show only P(1) value. and stop it. But i want to know all values. P(1) to P(121).

**Where is the problem? Are there any problem about loops?**

```
       PROGRAM odev
        dimension P(121)
c       div(ro.v.fi)=div(r.gradfi)+a-bfi
c       P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=P(4)=P(5)=P(6)=P(7)=P(8)=P(9)=P(10)=P(11)=100
c       P(12)=P(23)=P(34)=P(45)=P(56)=P(67)=P(78)=P(89)=P(100)=P(111)=100
c       P(22)=P(33)=P(44)=P(55)=P(66)=P(77)=P(88)=P(99)=P(110)=P(121)=0
c       P(112)=P(113)=P(114)=P(115)=P(116)=P(117)=P(118)=P(119)=P(120)=0
   50  PRINT *, "Hangi yontemle cozum yapmak istiyorsunuz?"
        PRINT *, "Merkezi farklar icin 1"
        PRINT *, "Upwind icin 2"
        PRINT *, "Hybrid icin 3"
        PRINT *, "Powerlaw icin 4 giriniz"
        READ *, DE
        PRINT *, "iterasyon saysn giriniz"
        read*, iter
        IF (DE.eq.1)  THEN
        GO TO 10
        ELSE IF (DE.eq.2)  THEN
        GO TO 20
        ELSE IF (DE.eq.3)  THEN
        GO TO 30
        ELSE IF (DE.eq.4)  THEN
        GO TO 40
        ELSE
        PRINT *, "Lutfen 1-4 aral§nda giriŸ yapnz"
        GO TO 50
        END IF
    5  do I=1,11
       P(I)=100
       end do
    6  do I=12,111,11
       P(I)= 100
       end do
    7  do I=22,121,11
       P(I)=0
       end do
    8  do I=112,120
       P(I)=0
       end do
   10 PRINT *, "Merkezi farklar metodu"
c      tanimlanan formule gore 10*10 hucreli grid
c      sistem icin hesap yapar
       do 3 n=1, iter
        DO 4 I=13, 109
       P(I)=(0.5*P(I+1)+1.5*P(I-1)-P(I-11)+3*P(I+11)+10)/6
    4 continue
    3 continue
        GO TO 60
   20  PRINT *, "Upwind metodu "
       do n=1, iter
        DO I=13, 109
        P(I)=(P(I+1)+2*P(I-1)+P(I-11)+5*P(I+11)+10)/11
        END DO
       end do
        GO TO 60
   30  PRINT *, "Hybrid metodu "
        do n=1, iter
        DO I=13, 109
        P(I)=(0.5*P(I+1)+1.5*P(I-1)+4*P(I+11)+10)/8
        END DO
       end do
        GO TO 60
   40  PRINT *, "Powerlaw metodu "
        do n=1, iter
        DO I=13, 109
       P(I)=(0.591*P(I+1)+1.591*P(I-1)+0.078*P(I-11)+4.078*P(I+11)+10)/8.338
        END DO
       end do
        GO TO 60
   60  PRINT *, "Tesekkurler"
       do 11 I=1,121
       print *, I, P(I)
       pause
   11  continue
       END
```

Edit;

From **@High Performance Mark** advices

> ```
>   60  PRINT *, "Tesekkurler"
>        do 11 I=1,121
>        print *, I, P(I)
> c       pause
>    11  continue
> ```

It's work now. But P(13) to P(109) values shown >Nan

P(1) to P(12) nearly 1e-40  (Must be 100)
P(110) to P(121) nearly 1e-38

I think there is another problem...

Edit 2;

From **@francescalus** advices

```
c       P(112)=P(113)=P(114)=P(115)=P(116)=P(117)=P(118)=P(119)=P(120)=0
    5  do I=1,11
       P(I)=100
       end do
    6  do I=12,111,11
       P(I)= 100
       end do
    7  do I=22,121,11
       P(I)=0
       end do
    8  do I=112,120
       P(I)=0
       end do
   50  PRINT *, "Hangi yontemle cozum yapmak istiyorsunuz?"
```

From **@agentp** advices

```
SELECT CASE (N)
CASE (1)
PRINT *, "Merkezi farklar metodu"
    do 3 n=1, iter
    DO 4 I=13, 109
    P(I)=(0.5*P(I+1)+1.5*P(I-1)-P(I-11)+3*P(I+11)+10)/6
4 continue
3 continue
    GO TO 60
CASE (2)
PRINT *, "Upwind metodu "
    do n=1, iter
    DO I=13, 109
    P(I)=(P(I+1)+2*P(I-1)+P(I-11)+5*P(I+11)+10)/11
    END DO
    end do
    GO TO 60
CASE (3)
PRINT *, "Hybrid metodu "
    do n=1, iter
    DO I=13, 109
    P(I)=(0.5*P(I+1)+1.5*P(I-1)+4*P(I+11)+10)/8
    END DO
    end do
    GO TO 60
CASE (4)
PRINT *, "Powerlaw metodu "
    do n=1, iter
    DO I=13, 109
    Z=8.338
   P(I)=(0.591*P(I+1)+1.591*P(I-1)+0.078*P(I-11)+4.078*P(I+11)+10)/Z
    END DO
    end do
    GO TO 60
END SELECT
```

Finally works now...

Comment: The initial assignments of `P` (lines labelled 5 up to 10) are never executed.  Whatever the value of `DE`, and the subsequent jumps, `P` is referenced before it is defined.  Getting results you want in this case would just be a matter of luck.

Comment: this is an excellent illustration of why you should never ever use `goto` .. rewrite this using `SELECT CASE` , ( or an `if then` structure if you really must use f77 )

Comment: glad its working -- you do not need the `goto` in `select case` however.

Comment: As @agentp has observed the `goto` statements at the end of each case are redundant.  It makes the code look like C, *shudder*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines

```
   print *, I, P(I)
   pause
```

tell the program to print the first element of `P` and then to `pause`.  On many computers any user input at that time, such as pressing a key, will cause the program to continue.  In your code that would result in the next element of `P` being written to the terminal, and the program pausing again.

Try taking the line `pause` out and see what happens.  Or sit there like a monkey and press a key 120 times.

Then throw the program away and rewrite it in modern Fortran; it causes me pain to look at FORTRAN77 .